# Encryption differencies between cookies.signed and session?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies, encryption, ruby-on-rails-4, session-cookies

The value set in both `cookies.signed` and `session` are encrypted.

Do the encryption techniques differ? If so, why?

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41467012/what-is-the-difference-between-signed-and-encrypted-cookies-in-rails