# User Roles in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This may be more of a conceptual question. I've got a user table and I need to provide roles for each of the users. For example I would like for some users to create customers and some to only view customers. I figure that I could create an association like this:

```
User has_one :role
Role belongs_to :user
```

With this structure, I could create `boolean` fields on the `Role` model such as `can_create_customer`. If I did, then I could use the following code to check for permissions based on every user:

```
if role.can_create_customer?
    Customer.create(name: "Test")
end
```

Is there a better way of accomplishing the same thing?

Comment: Have you tried looking at [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=rails+roles+gem)? The first bit may be helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how I do user roles and rights.

I create the following models:

```
class Role < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  has_and_belongs_to_many :rights
  validates :name, presence: true
end

class Right < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :roles
  validates :name, presence: true
end
```

Make sure you have proper constraints and indexes set in your database:

```
add_index :roles, :name, unique: true
add_index :rights, :name, unique: true
```

From there, you will need join tables for `roles_users` as well as `rights_roles` (because it's a many to many)

Then in seeds I create a few roles and rights:

```
role_admin = Role.create!(name: 'admin')               
role_admin.rights.create!(name: 'full_access')         

role_cm = Role.create!(name: 'company_manager')     
role_cm.rights.create!(name: 'edit_company')        
role_cm.rights.create!(name: 'edit_all_invoices')      
role_cm.rights.create!(name: 'edit_all_users')
```

Then you need to assign one or more roles to your user

```
current_user.roles << Role.find_by(name: 'company_manager')
```

Now, I simply check the roles/rights on login, and store it in a session along with the `user_id`

```
def session_login(user)
  session[:user_id] = user.id
  session[:rights] = user.list_rights
end
```

And you can access roles/rights with several `JOIN` sql statements efficiently. You want to store it in a session on login so you dont need to make this query for every request. It does mean however if you change roles/rights in the middle of your users session they will need to log back out and in again to see the updated changes

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  def list_roles
    roles.map(&:name)
  end

  def list_rights
    Right.joins(roles: :roles_users).where('roles_users.user_id = ?', id).map(&:name)
  end
end
```

**Final notes**

Now, when you do your 'checking', make sure you verify based on RIGHTS (dont check a users' role)

You can make this helper method

```
def current_user_has_right?(right)
  return false unless session[:rights]
  session[:rights].include? right
end
```

You can authorize! an entire controller for instance in this way:

```
def authorize!
  not_found unless current_user_has_right?('full_access')
end
```

Comment: This is great! I do have one question regarding security. Couldn't a user technically alter their session variable to include a right they didn't originally have and gain access to an unauthorized portion of the site? The only way I could think to get around that would be to actually make the query for each request. I guess if you encrypt the session then that wouldn't be an issue.

Comment: No, a user session is not editable by a user because it's signed. There are cases where the session data WILL be visible to the user (unless you also choose to encrypt the session), but in no cases (at least with a default rails install) will the user be able to hand-edit a session variable.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41467012/what-is-the-difference-between-signed-and-encrypted-cookies-in-rails

Comment: Im 90% sure that Rails 5 both signs and encrypts cookies by default (it used to only sign)

Comment: One last question. Why are you using `add_index` on the tables? I thought this was to only be used on columns that had many identical values.

Comment: no, it's adding an index AND a constraint. The index is used because you might want to find a specific role. To do that, it means `name` is going to be in the `WHERE` clause, so it should be indexed. The second, and more important thing, is that it's adding a unique index so that you cant have duplicate values. That could be bad, because say you add an `edit_posts` right... and want to go modify it later. You dont want to accidentially edit one and not realize you have that right duplicated. It should be 1 role, 1 right, and a many to many relationship linking them all

Comment: (so a right can be shared by multiple roles, you wouldnt have a duplicate right for each role)